# How can I run a series of queries/commands at once in Vertica?

Tags: vertica

Currently I am using Vertica on `Ubuntu` from the terminal as `dbadmin`. I am using `admintools` to connect a database and then executing queries like `Create Table`, `Select`, `Insert` in the terminal.

Is there any way I can write the commands in any external text file and execute all the query at once? Like for Oracle, We can create a SQL file in Notepad++ and then run all the queries in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only can you use scripts, but it's a good practice for any operation that you might need to repeat.

From the vsql prompt, use [the \i command](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/Meta-Commands/iFILE.htm) to run a script:

```
vsql> \i create_tables.sql
```

From outside the vsql prompt, you can invoke vsql with [-f filename](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/CommandLineOptions/fFilename--fileFilename.htm).

File paths, if not absolute, are relative to the current working directory.

Comment: What is the default working directory of vsql? I mean where do i first create the create_tables.sql file? Can I do it from the terminal or as a dbadmin?

Comment: @user3503711 default working directory of vsql is "/opt/vertica/bin/vsql" but you can pass the full file path of your script as an argument

Comment: @IddoE I just tested with an unqualified file name.  It looked in cwd, which for me was /home/dbadmin, not in /opt/vertica/bin.  And anyway, do you want your users writing into /opt/vertica/bin?  I don't.

Comment: or... `vsql -f <sql_script>`